# 2 different DataAnnotation validation styles with css

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2, and am using the DataAnnotation for validation of fields on my website, but I would like for the error messages to have two different styles depending on the form.  I know DataAnnotation uses these 2 css classes:

```
.input-validation-error
{
   background-color: #ffeeee;
   border: solid 2px #ff9999;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

My question is, can you specify which css class the validations use, and if so how?  Thank you guys for your help in advance.  I have not had any luck finding this answer thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your forms different ids and adapt your CSS. Example:

```
<form action="/foo" method="post" id="form1">
    ...
</form>

<form action="/foo" method="post" id="form2">
    ...
</form>
```

and then have different CSS rules:

```
#form1 .input-validation-error
{
   background-color: red;
   border: solid 2px #ff9999;
}

#form2 .input-validation-error
{
   background-color: blue;
   border: solid 2px #ff9999;
}
```

Comment: It worked!  Thank you, and for anyone who also wants to use this method, don't forget to delete the cache to get rid of the old css file from the browser before trying it out. ;-)